# Bootstrap 4 navbar disappears on resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

It works perefectly fine on large screen but disappears on resizing. I have not set any height property for the navbar. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jokersspirit/jym1s0xk/4/) I know the question is been asked many number of times. But I never came across a solution that works.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}

nav .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

nav .bg-custom{
    background-color: white !important;
}

nav .nav-link{
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's there. hidden on the right. no need to change `bg` as you did in updated fiddle.

just add class `navbar-light`
so,

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">`
will be

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">`

and it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your fiddle. 
Click on the right side, there is a button there, you just can't see it because it is all white (it is the toggler).
The Navbar will expand (dropdown) to show the contents. 
You just need to change the color of the button.

Comment: Changed the fiddle bg to red. But unable to see

Comment: You will need to change the color of the "navbar-toggler-icon"

Comment: Try this: .navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid white;
}